# Rebind and Reinitialize jQuery UI sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the following code to sort my form element.

```
//sortable form element with in form
function sortableFormElement() {

    //destroy and unbind
    var builderWrapper = $(".builder-wrapper form");
    if (builderWrapper.hasClass('ui-sortable')) {
        builderWrapper.sortable("destroy");
        //builderWrapper.unbind();//dangarous
    }

    //rebind
    builderWrapper.sortable({
        connectWith: ".form-group",
        cursor: "move",
        tolerance: "pointer",
        zIndex: 9999,
        revert: "invalid",
        dropOnEmpty: true,
        forcePlaceholderSize: true,
        placeholder: "ni-sortable-placeholder",
        start: function (e, ui) {
            ui.item.toggleClass("ni-sortable-dragging");
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            ui.item.toggleClass("ni-sortable-dragging");
        },
        receive: function (event, ui) {
            $("body").trigger("resize")
        }
    }).disableSelection();
}
```

`$(".builder-wrapper form").sortable(options)` works fine for page loaded, but does not work when I add element dynamically into form. I have used `$(".builder-wrapper form").sortable('destroy);` or `$(".builder-wrapper form").unbind();` or `$(".builder-wrapper form").sortable('refresh');`, no one can not help me.

I am using the jQuery version `jquery-2.1.4.min.js` and jQueryUI version `jquery-ui-1.11.2.min.js`

Comment: @MKA, it is the part of my project, I am trying to write jsfiddle.

Comment: @MKA, Thanks, I have found the solution that after binding all of event (click, mousedown...) then bind sortable, its work for me. Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mdshohelrana85/ac8wxphc/2/

Comment: well its working fine if you don't bind after click event http://jsfiddle.net/ac8wxphc/3/